# How can I successfully integrate Yahoo sign-in into my Django website using Yahoo API?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, yahoo, yahoo-api

I want to integrate Yahoo sign-in into my website, but I have been unsuccessful so far despite registering an app on Yahoo. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this integration?
How can I successfully integrate Yahoo login into my website after registering an app on Yahoo?

Need guidance on integrating Yahoo login into my Django Rest Framework website. Registered Yahoo app but facing issues. Seeking help in achieving successful integration.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. It includes Django authentication systems for google, yahoo, facebook and also github.

Install it with: `pip install django-allauth`